# Git Commands inside Powershell Script to Run when Pipeline is Triggered

Tags: powershell, bitbucket-pipelines

I can run this script locally and it works, but when run in my Bitbucket pipeline the Git inside is not valid.  I have the git command inside my Powershell script that is called from the Pipeline.  Is there a way to get this inside of my Powershell script?  This returns the files that have been updated in a commit. With the file names I then update these files on another server where the files live for automation.  Here is my ps1 script that is called from the yaml file.

```
$jamsBaseUrl = "https://jamsapi.energycap.com/jams"
$hdrs = @{}
$JamsUserName = "username here"
$JamsPassword = "password here"
$updatedJobs = git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~1


#Log into Bitbucket
$headers=@{}
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic token here")

# Log into JAMS
$loginReq = @{
    "username"=$JamsUserName;
    "password"=$JamsPassword;
    "grant_type"=$null;
    "refresh_Token"=$null
}
try {
    Write-Host "Logging into JAMS..."
    Write-Host "This is the commit..." $BITBUCKET_COMMIT
    $loginBody = $loginReq|ConvertTo-Json
    $loginResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "$jamsBaseUrl/api/authentication/login" -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $hdrs -Body $loginBody 
    Write-Host "Logged in as $JamsUserName."
}
catch {
    throw "Unable to log into JAMS as user $JamsUserName : $_"
}

$token = $loginResult.access_token
$hdrs.Add("Authorization", "Bearer $token")

Foreach ($job in $updatedJobs){
    Write-Host $job
    $clientJobs = $job -split '/'
    $clientDir = $clientJobs[0]
    $jobName = $clientJobs[1]
    $source = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/mycompany/testing/src/master/$clientDir/$jobName" -Method GET -Headers $headers
    
    $jobjson =@{
        "JobName" = $jobName;
        "source" = $source;
        "ParentFolderName" = "\Testing\$clientDir";
        "MethodName" = "PowerShell"
    }
    $body = $jobjson |ConvertTo-Json
    $updateResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Method PUT -Uri "$jamsBaseUrl/api/job" -Headers $hdrs -Body $body -ContentType "application/json"

    Write-Host $jobName
    Write-Host $updateResult
}
```

Here is my yml file:

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:latest

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          script:
            - pwsh ./JamsConnector.ps1
            - echo "This script runs only on commit to the master branch"
```

And here is the error in when the pipeline runs the script

[image]

Comment: you could remove the unused variable assignment and then it should work not only locally but also remotely in the bitbucket pipeline. but perhaps you were a bit short describing the problem and there is more meaning behind the assigment? if so, please provide reference that bitbucket has support for powershell, IIRC there is only shell or bash shell and not power-shell.

Comment: “Git inside is not valid.” - what happens that make you think this? Do you get an error message? How does the behaviour differ from what you expect? Note that ci platforms tend not to do a *full* clone of all branches by default so commands that rely on all refs being present may fail for that reason. I’ve seen this on GitLab, GitHub and TeamCity so it may be the same for BitBucket Pipelines. If you can post any error messages they might help diagnose the issue…

Comment: Here’s how to do it in BitBucket Pipelines - https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/How-to-get-all-branches-from-pipelines/qaq-p/1982724 in case that *is* the issue…